# What is the name and notation of a graph that models a tridimensional grid of cubic cells?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph which models a tridimensional grid of cubic cells, where each vertex represents a cell, and each edge represents coincident faces between the cells, what is the name and notation applicable to this kind of graph and its variations?

Please, consider the examples A, B and C bellow, providing their correspondent names and notations if possible:

- Graph A represents a 3x3x3 grid of cells.
- Graph B represents a 3x3x3 grid of cells but without the cell 000.
- Graph C represents a 3x3x2 grid of cells.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know if there's a particular name for the graphs you're describing. There's such a thing as a "cubic graph", but that term refers to graphs such that all the vertices have degree 3. That is not the case for the graphs you listed since many of the vertices have degree 4, but who knows, maybe there's some sort of generalization for cubic graphs. Although there's graphs such as *stars*, *wheels*, etc that very much get their name from their appearance, usually graphs' names have more to do with their properties.

Comment: Thank you @Damascuz ! I found them as "Grid Graph".

Comment: Oh right! I knew about grid graphs vaguely, but didn't know they went beyond "two dimensions". Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it is called Lattice Graph, or Mesh Graph, or Grid Graph.

The notation used is $G_{m,n,r,...}$, where the subscripts correspond to the amount of vertices used for the cartesian product.

Given that, Graphs A, B and C are:

- A: Grid Graph $G_{3,3,3}$
- B: Not sure about this one (...maybe "Grid Graph $G_{3,3,3}$(000 $\notin$ G)"?)
- C: Grid Graph $G_{3,3,2}$

Source:

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GridGraph.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph